# navigateUpFromSameTask ends App

Tags: android, navigation

I enter my app via entry in notification bar. When I press back button then my app closes - not good but that's what I could expect. But If I click on the title which is implemented as navigation item this way

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

then it also ends my app. 
I would expect to load the activity which is defined as parent in the manifest:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int i = item.getItemId();
        if (i == android.R.id.home) {
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
```

manifest:

```
<activity>
android:name="currentActivity"
<meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                    android:value="myapp.ParentActivity"/>
```

heres the notification intent:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext)
                .setContentTitle(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name_launcher));

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(mContext, newAct.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(mContext);
        // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(prevAct.class);
        // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                        Consts.NOTIFICATIONIDACTIVE,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
```

How do I fix this?

Regards,
Tata

Comment: What flags are you setting when starting activity from Notification?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html), on the section *Navigate up with a new back stack*. I would also recommend to add to your manifest the following line:

```
android:parentActivityName="Your parent activity name"
```

Inside the activity tag.